# Open an external Modal Box with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i want to open an external modal box on my page, im using bootstrap

Main HTML1 (index.html)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="modal.html" >Assumir Tarefa</button>
```

Modal HTML (modal.html)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Posting the bootstrap documentation example is not going to help anyone... what is the problem you are experiencing? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  We prefer questions to... well, have a question.  Giving us a statement and letting us guess what you mean is not going to get you much of a response.  Please read the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the help

Comment: [The `remote` option of Bootstrap modals is **deprecated**.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/8340d664ce5875c15393017e4f3b06c458215469) Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing how a modal works.  You're putting the modal code in a separate html file and trying to call that.

Change the calling button to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="#myModal" >Assumir Tarefa</button>
```

And put that code you pasted from modal.html in the same file, index.html (along with all the other bootstrap required files).  If you're unsure of what else you need I would take a look at [Bootstrap Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)